# Is it a good practice to include generated classes into managed test folder?

Tags: java, testing, protocol-buffers, code-generation, thrift

I have a code which relies on generated thrift and protobuf classes by code-user (that's a library).

I want to test it using my own generated thrift and protobuf classes (they, probably, will not change very often). So, for that i can include dependencies for `build.gradle` to be able to generate them. The problem occurs if i want to do the same in CI, because i have to install thrift and protobuf compilers on building machine.

I can avoid this if i generate all classes for testing using my pc, for example, and include them in test-source code.

The main question: is it a good or acceptable practice or i should prefer to re-generate each time these classes?

Comment: If this is too troublesome for your build process, you could split out the protobuf stuff into a separate module, build a jar file for that (from the generated sources) and include it into your main project as a dependency.  But unless you already have multiple projects and a way to publish jar files that is probably even more trouble.

Comment: It depends. Both approaches have their pros and cons. The general consensus tends towards excluding generated code from SCC, but there are indeed cases where this turns out to be quite helpful, for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, it's a good practice to only include the `.proto` file in the source code, and re-generate these classes when you compile your project.

Because you might change the `.proto` file and the Protobuf compiler might upgrade, when whatever happens, you need to re-generate these classes. However, if you commit these classes into your source code, you might forget to commit new version of these classes, and it's also hard to do a code review on the changes of these auto-generated code. Instead, code review on the `.proto` file should be much more easier.